# Sending class containing Collection through network stream

Tags: java, android, stream, synchronization

I want to send through ObjectStream an object of class: (Packet is `Serializable`)

```
public class ServerPlayersListPacket extends Packet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7141960214853425631L;

    private ArrayList<Player> players;


    public ServerPlayersListPacket(ArrayList<Player> players) {
        this.setPlayers(players);
    }


    public ArrayList<Player> getPlayers() {
        return new ArrayList<Player>(Collections.synchronizedList(players));
    }


    public void setPlayers(ArrayList<Player> players) {
        this.players = players;
    }
}
```

But there is a problem with `ArrayList`. While reciving it from the other site I got `OptionalDataException`.

I found it's issue related to `ArrayList` synchronization. But how to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My trick is:

1. send initial packet `ServerPlayersListInitPacket`
2. send `ServerNextPlayerPacket` in loop with one `Player` per `Packet`

This solution also allows client site to update players list dynamically which is more smooth.

Answer (score 0):

1. ArrayList is not synchronized. Vector is.
2. For streaming you need fields to be serializable, not synchronized. Try turning on different fields by "transient", so, you´ll find the problem one.